# Table viewer width increases each time section expanded

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created a Table which is inside the form Section .Each time it expands the table size(Width) grows. I am using TableColoumnLayout for the table viewer composite.

I have checked this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=215997 .I have no luck.

Any advice?

```
 objectiveSection = toolkit.createSection(composite,        Section.DESCRIPTION|Section.TITLE_BAR|
              Section.TWISTIE|Section.EXPANDED);
       objectiveSection.setActiveToggleColor(toolkit.getHyperlinkGroup().getActiveForeground());
    objectiveSection.setToggleColor(toolkit.getColors().getColor(FormColors.SEPARATOR));


    GridData data=new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
    objectiveSection.setLayoutData(data);
    toolkit.createCompositeSeparator(objectiveSection); 
    toolkit.adapt(objectiveSection);

    /**
     * Creating a client inside the section
     */
    Composite objective = toolkit.createComposite(objectiveSection, SWT.BORDER);


    /**
     * creating the object table model and object table.
     */
    TableModel objectiveModel=new ObjectiveTableModel();

    GridData gds = new GridData(GridData.FILL,GridData.FILL,true,true);

    objectiveTable=new  CustomTable(objectiveModel, objective, true, true, gds);
    /**
     * column for object viewer     
     */
    objectiveTable.createTableViewerColumn("List of Behaviors", 0);
    objectiveTable.enableCellEdit();
    objectiveTable.autoFocus();
    toolkit.adapt(objective);

    objectiveSection.setText("Behaviours");
    objectiveSection.setDescription("The section contains the Behaviours of the selected operation"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    objectiveSection.setClient(objective);
    objectiveSection.setExpanded(true);
    objectiveSection.setEnabled(true);
    objectiveSection.addExpansionListener(new ExpansionAdapter() {
        public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) {
            form.reflow(false);
        }
    });
```

My table will get the values dynamically .Each time i am re sizing the column

```
     this.table.setRedraw(false);   
     for (int i = 0, n = this.table.getColumnCount(); i < n; i++){
       this.table.getColumn(i).pack();
       int minWidth=this.table.getColumn(i).getWidth();
       this.layout.setColumnData(this.table.getColumn(i), new ColumnWeightData(25,minWidth));
    }

    this.table.setRedraw(true );
    this.composite.layout();
```

Comment: What grows? The width? The height?

Comment: @greg-449 width of the table grows

Answer (score 0):

It seems to happen because of the following line:

```
GridData gds = new GridData(GridData.FILL,GridData.FILL,true,true);
```

You request that the table will fill its container and grab excess space.
Try instead:

```
GridData gds = new GridData(GridData.CENTER,GridData.CENTER,false,false);
```